# Find the noise figure for a receiver front end

Tags: noise, microwave

I'm editing this question as suggested in the comments. This is indeed a homework question for an old course that I'm reviewing, and the idea is not to solve it for me, but to show me how such questions can be solved. In particular, what is the way to calculate the NF for an entire system when we have it for each sub system alone. Since I'm not sure what should be taken into account, I'm including all relevant information.

The operating frequencies of the below receiver is 1.574 GHz to 1.576 GHz, the ADC requires at least 10 dB of SNR. What is the overall noise figure of the front end?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like a homework assignment. It is OK to ask about those **however** you have to show what you have tried to find the answer. You show nothing. Hint: suppose there's a signal of -20 dBm at the antenna with SNR of 40 dB. At what level will the noise be at the antenna? What will the signal and noise be at the output of each block? Hint 2: Note that noise is also "just a signal", however it **is** affected by the NF while the "normal" signal is not.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this, not a numeric answer, but the way to solve it.

Comment: Then next time, instead of copy-pasting the question, ask **how** to approach this question and list the things you already know, for example that a NF = 2 means that the SNR is degraded by 2 dB. Then you get more sympathy and a better answer.

Comment: "I'm including all relevant information" -- that would include the work you've already done up to the point at which you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I would prefer giving the way to approach the question rather solving it here.

The bandpass filter section right after the receiving antenna has a loss of 2 dB (or, a gain of -2dB). You then have the amplifier (LNA mostly) followed by the mixer section and a second BPF. What is your overall noise figure? Isn't it the ratio of the input SNR to the output SNR?

Consider the circuit in sections (or stages)

1. The first bandpass filter: The gain is -2 dB while the noise figure is 2 dB.
2. For the amplifier section, the gain and noise figure have been mentioned. This is second stage and the overall noise figure at this stage depends on the noise figure of the current stage as well as the noise figure and gain of the previous stage.
3. Similar to stage 2, the values have been mentioned. Similar noise figure and gain dependencies follow here.
4. We have a second BPF whose specifications are same as the first one.

[image: NFcalc]

Answer (score -2):

NF total = 2dB + 10log(1.596 + (6.309-1)/31.62 + (1.585 - 1)/3.61) = 4.834 dB

Comment: We don't solve homework question here, and anyway, I don't think that answer would've help much the OP getting better (which is the point of homework).

Comment: What if this was the wrong answer? Could you prove/explain that it is correct?